# Convert "2 days 12 hours 15 minutes" into Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server in which working period is stored as "2 days 12 hours 15 minutes" or " 5 hours 45 minutes" or "35 minutes" and I want to convert this into Minutes only. Can anyone help in SQL Query.

Comment: I hope this is to fix your design (and store the duration as an `int` value). Could you have any other types of durations? Such as "Weeks", "Years", "Seconds"?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Can't change my db design, No other types of duration, such as weeks ,years, seconds.

Comment: Can I convert this "2 days 12 hours 15 minutes" into minutes such as "3615" in my sql query.

Comment: @MuhammadMansoormehrban the data is with the word day, hour and minutes?

Comment: This is a nightmare design to work with. t-sql is not great at string manipulation like this. Honestly I would go with a CLR function if you are stuck using this string. You will need to split your string on a space and keep the ordinal position. Then you can evaluate the value of the even numbered values and find the value of the one previous. I suspect there are going to be edge cases not defined here too. Things like `1 day 1 minute 4 hours`.

Comment: You have to provide test data. How does just 5 minutes appear, for example? Start by finding spaces in the text using charindex and parsing the text into 6 tokens (6 columns) and share your effort

Comment: @SeanLange - unfortunately the fun never stops: "The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). Beginning with SQL Server 2022 (16.x) Preview, the argument and output column are available in SQL Server."

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz indeed. I was happy to see they finally fixed the huge miss with their string_split function by omitting one of the more important elements. Even happier that it will be included with 2022 whenever that gets released...maybe late October???

Answer (score 2):

you can use this solution:

```
declare @value as nvarchar(50)='2 days 12 hours 15 minutes'
--'35 minutes'--'5 hours 45 minutes'--'2 days 12 hours 15 minutes'

select 
 case when charindex('days',@value)-1 <0 then 0 else 
 (substring (@value,0,charindex('days',@value)-1) *1440 ) end +
 (substring (@value,charindex('hours',@value)-3,2) * 60)+
 (substring (@value,charindex('minutes',@value)-3,2)) as [Minutes]
```